# Why do I have to repeat an intro sentence?

Tags: c, string, char

I wan to read two char so I do the following code:

```c
main() {
    char a,b;

    printf("\nEnter the first char.. ");
    a=getchar();
    printf("\nEnter the second char.. ");
    b=getchar();
    b=getchar();       //<--I've to add this sentence because the previously doesn't work

    printf("\nFirst char --> %c",a);
    printf("\nSecond char --> %c",b);

}
```

The code **should not** work but it does. The output is the correct:

> First char --> z
>
> Second char --> z ('z' or the char there I wan to)

If I remove the second `getchar()` then the output is:

> First char --> z
>
> Second char --> (Here there is no char)

## How can I remove the second `getchar()` without get any error?

Because `fflush(stdin)` before `getchar()` doesn't work.

Comment: are you typing a carriage return after each letter? if so, that's why.

Comment: @Geoffrey Yes, but how can i solve it?

Comment: `getchar` takes one ONE character, not two... a carriage return is a character also. The method you should be looking for if you want to accept more then one character is `gets` which will read until a carriage return is entered.

Comment: @Geoffrey But I wan to read one char, not two.

Comment: You still have to read the additional character even if you don't intend on using it.

Comment: @Geoffrey Ok. Sounds like there is no `fflush()` that works here. But, if still isn't clear, I prefer to use twice the same function before do an algorithm that remove the last character or something like that. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by the other answers, the problem was caused by the **carriage return**.

There are many ways solve this, some more complex than others. Therefore I will indicate the simplest method I've found:

As [the GNU website indicate](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Character-Input.html) the most appropriate function for this is `getc(stream)` and I quote:

> This is just like **fgetc**, except that it is permissible (and
>   typical) for it to be implemented as a macro that **evaluates the stream**
>    **argument more than once**. **getc** is often highly optimized, so it is
>   usually **the best function to use to read a single character**.

I put it into practice **but** it still have the **CR** problem, so I printed the result of this function and notice that it **return 10 when CR**.
After this I tried to get functionality and clarity for the code. Doing everything possible for this, now my code  is the following:

```c
main() {
    char a,b;

    printf("\nEnter the first char.. ");
    if ((a=getc(stdin))==10) a=getc(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter the second char.. ");
    if ((b=getc(stdin))==10) b=getc(stdin);

    printf("\nFirst char --> %c",a);
    printf("\nSecond char --> %c",b);

}
```

And the nice output:

> First char --> z
>
> Second char --> z ('z' or the char there I wan to)

---

I've learned that all the programs need they own solution, different than the others, and that is the reason *(I think)* for that are so many functions. What I can say is "Always have to adapt the program. Maybe this sentence works for me but is not guaranteed that gonna work for other codes."

Thanks to all the guys that helped me!

Answer (score 7):

Try this: make a file `data`, *two bytes* in size containing precisely `ab`. Now say:

```
./myprogram < data
```

And voila.

The point is that when you operate your terminal and press `a` followed by the enter key, you are sending *two* characters to the process, first `a` and then `\n`, the newline. So the second `getchar` picks up the newline.

(And your terminal does not permit you to send individual characters without pressing Enter, since it has a line buffer that it fills up before sending anything.)

In short, `getchar` is a poor I/O primitive, and you should almost always prefer `fgets` to read entire lines and process those.

Comment: You're right, the problem is the carriage return. With `fgets()` I'll need to make a data structure. Don't you know other function that can work for me?

Comment: @Lucio: You don't need a "data structure" for `fgets`, just a char array. It's by far the preferable method, because it gives you an entire line of input and lets you process it as a string rather than a stream.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your `getchar()` function leaves the newline character in the keyboard buffer. This means the first `b=getchar();` reads a newline character and the second one reads the actual input you expect. A more elegant approach would be to ignore the newline character if you have an `ignore()` function available.

Comment: To which you're referring to is that `ignore()` should process the **carriage return**? Do not you think that would be considered inefficient? Maybe I'm wrong in thinking that.

Comment: What do you mean by inefficient? You have to skip the newline character somehow. Using `getchar()` does that, but when reading the code, this isn't entirely clear. On the other hand, an `ignore()` makes it more clear that you are skipping the next character in the input stream.

Comment: Ok, maybe you're right. a `ignore()` function, sound like a good idea. I'll try to implement it. Thanks for your tip!

Comment: That's certainly one way to do it, but not quite what I had in mind. My original thought was to find an `ignore()` function from a standard library. In that line of thought, I also would like to know where your `getchar()` function comes from? Maybe the same library already has an `ignore()` function.

Comment: The only library there I used was **stdio.h**. I don't used the **string.h** library or other.

Comment: I was expecting an `ignore()` function in `stdio.h`, however, I don't see one in [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io). If you only want to ignore one character at a time, it wouldn't be difficult to make your own function using `getchar()`. In fact, it wouldn't be difficult to make one that ignores a given number of characters, either.

Answer (score 0):

[getchar()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/getchar/) only gets one char. newline takes one character, ergo you need the extra getchar() in your code to get the desired input/output.

Comment: You're right! There isn't another solution that can help me? The goal is not having to use the second `getchar()`.